# Don't you need centralised database to verify NFT authenthicity

Tags: ethereum, nft

So I have had this question for a while, and I haven't been able to find an answer yet, although it seems like a very basic question. Apologies if it is already answered somewhere and I missed it.

So lets say big artist Alice mints an NFT of her art. Lets call this NFT A. This NFT is identified by a token, and we can verify who is the owner, and thus also which adress minted it.

But here is the catch. Let's scam artist Bob mints NFT B of the same art piece. Now when you go on a marketplace there are two NFT's of seemingly the same art piece. So you need now to find which one is the 'real one'. To do that, you need to look at who minted it, and verify that it is the real artist.

But how do you do that in a de-centralized manner ? It feels like I would need to confirm that an address belongs to Alice, but how can I get/confirm this information ?

In the case of big NFT's like the cryptopunks it is easy because everyone 'knows' which is the correct minting address, but for smaller artists it is literally impossible to tell, as far as I know. And this is (I think) one of the reasons that it is easy to 'steal' art piece by minting an NFT of it.

I guess this concern must have been considered time and time again, but I have not been able to find discussion about it.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by authenticity, but yes Opensea for example will give your project a checkbox thumbs up when you hit a certain volume.

Comment: Certainly, but then the NFT is useless... The authenthicity is given by Opensea, not the blockchain. Opensea could do the same thing skipping the blockchain part entirely then

Comment: I guess it's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to verify that a contract belongs to an owner address? If so there is a read only owner property.

Comment: No, I know that this can be done. I am saying how do NFT's prevent people from just minting an art piece which don't belong to them, and then selling it as original. As far as I understand there is now real way to prevent that, without resorting to verification "outside" the decentralized environment. (I asked my question on ethereum stack exchange, as it is maybe more appropriate there)